# enumerating representatives of an equivalence class in modulo arithmetic

Tags: number-theory

I am trying to understand some equivalence classes in multiplication $\bmod (2^n-1)$ arithmetic. Not exactly sure what to call this type of algebraic structure since it's not a group (some members don't have multiplicative inverses... does that mean it's a [monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid)?) and I'm not that familiar with abstract algebra, so please pardon my terminology.

Each equivalence class is the set $\{k, 2k, 4k, ... 2^{n-1}k\}$ with $n$ distinct members.

For example, let's say we're looking at $n=6$. Then the equivalence classes are:

- $\{1,2,4,8,16,32\}$
- $\{3,6,12,24,48,33\}$
- $\{5,10,20,40,17,34\}$
- $\{7, 14, 28, 56, 49, 35\}$
- $\{11, 22, 44, 25, 50, 37\}$
- $\{13, 26, 52, 41, 19, 38\}$
- $\{15, 30, 60, 57, 51, 39\}$
- $\{23, 46, 29, 58, 53, 43\}$
- $\{31, 62, 61, 59, 55, 47\}$

with

- $\{9, 18, 36\}$ and $\{27, 54, 45\}$ excluded since they form a cycle of length 3
- $\{21, 42\}$ excluded since it forms a cycle of length 2

I'm not sure how to describe the entire set; the numbers that are excluded have a common factor with $2^{n-1}$ but numbers that are included sometimes also have common factors (e.g. $3, 7, 15$ in this example).

What I'm trying to do is to see if there's a direct way to enumerate a representative from each class, without having to check a majority of the  $2^{n-1}$ members, but there's no clear pattern here.

---

[Jyrki Lahtonen pointed out in another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2348868/120) that these are the cyclotomic cosets of 2 modulo $2^{n-1}$.

There's a relation to the conjugate roots of $GF(2^n$).

From http://web.ntpu.edu.tw/~yshan/algebra.pdf, here's an example of $n=4$ (look at the powers of $\alpha$):

[image]

[John Kerl calls this a "root chart"](http://johnkerl.org/doc/ffcomp.pdf) (terminology doesn't seem to be standard) and shows the same example for $n=6$ I mentioned earlier:

[image]

Comment: Hmm. Interestingly 3 and 7 are ok with 1 common factor, the elements that are out have 2 common factors  (3x3 and 3x7)